# How can I build specific Branch in Azure devOps CI?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have two environments in a single pipeline DEV and Preprod. For dev, I am using the development branch and for preprod I am using release-*.*.* branch. I created many tasks in that pipeline I need to set custom conditions for specific branches DEV is working fine but in prepord i have more than one release branch. I need to set a custom condition in Azure DevOps so that I can build any release branch and I don't want to set it manually every time.

This is the YAML format. But I am using **Classic Pipeline**

```
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
    name: env_external_preprod
    displayName: Prepod Conditional Download .env
# condition:** eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/releases-*')**
    inputs:
      secureFile: 447****d-****-****-****-fa1e****d30b
```

OR

[This is the custom condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awmY8.png)

[But It is showing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4ZuY.png)

[I change branch from here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWCtg.png)

I need to build specific branch but don't want to set manually every time.

Answer (score 0):

Classic pipelines also support this type of custom conditions, try to use this sample:

```
and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/releases'))
```

Examples: [Run for user topic branches, if succeeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cstages#run-for-user-topic-branches-if-succeeding)

[image]

Comment: Hello Shamrai,
This condition is working. Thank You for your support.